# does two different implementation of Aes has different cipher text?

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, aes

i am using a library 1 Aes algorithm implementation now i want to change it to another implementation of library 2 its working fine but the thing is its giving me diff encrypted data form library 1 , is it possible for Aes implementation with ECB mode 128 bit with same key and plain text but differs only in cipher text(encrypted data) for 2 different implementation?

i found one more thing that is if i pass input byte which is less then 16 byte then the encrypted data of both library is getting matched but again in library1 the decryption is perfect but in library2 its showing encrypt and decrypt are same(not exactly decrypting to original text) what would be the problem?

Comment: Are they padding it?  If not, and they use the same [cipher mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) and the same initialization vector, then no, they should produce exactly the same output.

Comment: A common root cause of such a difference, at least judging from what we see in Stack Overflow questions, is that the two different cases are using different **text encodings**. Remember, the input to the cipher is *bytes* not *text* - be sure you are sending the same *bytes* when you compare them.

Comment: i dont know they are padding it or not .what about if they are padding ?Blueraja i am using (unsigned char*) as an input to cipher in both case .

Comment: Side note: Don't use ECB. Use an authenticated semantically secure mode, such as AES-GCM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your comment that strings less than 16 bytes lead to the same output, along with your use of ECB (which you should never use), my suspicion is that one of your libraries does not actually use ECB, and instead defaults to CBC (which is a much better default) and that you are passing a NULL IV to CBC. If my theory is correct, then you should expect the first 16 bytes to always be the same, and differences to begin after that point.

The best solution to this is to convert all of your code from ECB (which is deeply broken in all but some very rare situations) to CBC or just about any other mode you can find. CBC is the most common, and you will need to pass it an randomly generated IV.

If switching modes is impossible, I would investigate your second library and determine how to set it into ECB mode, which it probably is not currently in. Whoever is relying on your encryption should be warned that using ECB mode leaks significant information about the plaintext. Sometimes it's barely encrypted at all. See the [entry at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) for a nice visual example of how bad it really is. This isn't some theoretical attack. It's really, really broken.

Comment: this was really helpful for me thank you i am not able to upvote it as i have less than 15 credit but thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, as the comments have pointed out.  Crypto is designed to show large changes in output for a small change in input.  Ideally a one bit change in the input will change 50% of the bits in the output.

The way to avoid most of the problems is to explicitly specify everything.  Don't rely on defaults as if the defaults are different between the two libraries then the output will differ.

1. Explicitly specify a character encoding to convert characters into bytes. UTF-8 is common.
2. Explicitly specify the encryption mode you are using.  CBC or CTR modes if you don't want authentication included, GCM if you do.
3. Explicitly specify the IV, using bytes, not characters, preferably.
4. Explicitly specify the padding to use. PKCS7 (aka PKCS5) is very common.

If you are still having problems then check that everything is *byte for byte* the same for both libraries.  Don't check characters, but bytes.  That is, check things after you have converted them to byte arrays and immediately before you pass them to the encryption method.

As a side note, ECB mode is insecure and leaks information.  It is only useful for testing the operation of a cypher method.  Use CBC, CTR or GCM mode, as I suggested above.  Those modes are secure, and GCM includes authentication.

Comment: "Crypto is designed to show large changes in output for a small change in input" That's not generally true. With semantically secure symmetric encryption the IV produces totally different outputs even without any changes, and without IV change propagation and security depends on a lot on the mode.

Comment: I count a change in the IV as a "change in input".

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of correct answers already here. The only thing which I want to mention, which wasn't mentioned before.

> it possible for Aes implementation with ECB mode 128 bit with same key
>   and plain text but differs only in cipher text(encrypted data) for 2
>   different implementation?

In the case, if algorithms implemented correctly, the same input (plain text, mode, IV, padding) **should** produce the same output (cipher text).

In the case, if you are using two established libraries, most likely the problem one of the mentioned before (difference in one of the inputs, encoding and so on).